# Extract string from between quotations python 3.4 serial port

Tags: python, extract, pyserial, quotations

I want to identify which serial port of my computer is being used, to do so I have (VSPE which is a virtual serial port emulator just like Eltima virtual serial port driver 7.1) and the following code

```
import sys
import glob
import serial
def serial_ports():
    """Lists serial ports
    :raises EnvironmentError:
        On unsupported or unknown platforms
    :returns:
        A list of available serial ports
    """
    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        ports = ['COM' + str(i + 1) for i in range(256)]
    elif sys.platform.startswith('linux') or     sys.platform.startswith('cygwin'):
        ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty[A-Za-z]*')
    elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
        ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty.*')
    else:
        raise EnvironmentError('Unsupported platform')
    result = []
    for port in ports:
        try:
            s = serial.Serial(port)
            s.close()
            result.append(port)
        except (OSError, serial.SerialException):
            pass
    return result
a=serial_ports()
print(a)
```

now this code gives me

```
>>>['COM9']
```

as an answer

my question is how can I get rid of  this: `['      ']`

I just want the `COM9` or at least the `9` and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`['COM9']` is a list with one elment. To get this element, use the index `0`.

```
l = ['COM9']
s = l[0]
```

If you want only the digit `9`, use

```
d = s[-1]
```

If you want to convert the result, which is `"9"`, to an integer, use

```
i = int(d)
```